# Angular/Typescript Eval and this

Tags: angular, typescript, this, eval

So I am having a problem understanding how eval works with this in typescript/angular. Could someone please help me get the eval to work here? This is just a demo program so just ignore the fact that the logic doesn't make sense. I would just like to have eval update a dynamic array with a dynamic value.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pfyt7q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  arrTest1 = [];
  arrTest2 = [];
  arrTest3 = [];

  constructor() {
    this.TestClass.Run("this.arrTest1 = [1];");
    this.TestClass.Run("this.arrTest2 = [2];");
    this.TestClass.Run("this.arrTest3 = [3];");
    console.log(this.arrTest1);   //Logs: [] (I want: [1])
    console.log(this.arrTest2);   //Logs: [] (I want: [2])
    console.log(this.arrTest3);   //Logs: [] (I want: [3])
  };

  TestClass = {
    Run : (pString) => {
      (0, eval)(pString);
      eval(pString);
    }
  };

}
```

Comment: This is normal, the arrTest arrays are assigned to the TestClass variable you can try logging this.TestClass to see the arrays. I am also wondering why do you need to eval those strings ?

Comment: How do I make eval assign the values to this.arrTest, not to this.TestClass.arrTest?...like I said this is just a demo that doesn't really make sense. My actual program has an http call which is hard to replicate in a demo to show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PS: The eval function is very dangerous and should be used with precaution !!!**

But, because I'm kind, I will show you how to make your code work: In order to specify the context of your eval function you can use the call javascript function like this:

```
this.TestClass.Run.call(this, "this.arrTest2 = [2];");
```

**PS2: Generally, you don't need to use the eval function, you can explain even without giving the whole code behind your desired behavior and people can help you figure out how to make it work.**

EDIT: If your desired behavior is to have dynamic arrays/values, you can use a simple object and add your attribute to it dynamically. Let say your object is A: You can use A[varName] to create an object attribute dynamically.

Comment: Dude thank you so much! I have been battling with this the whole day! And just because of your PS1 comment I will rethink my use of eval :)

Comment: `eval.call(this, pString)` executes in the global scope, the thing that you must remember is that the eval function is very tricky and is EVIL. it would be awesome if you can avoid using it. Here are two good articles explaining how and where eval executes: 
http://2ality.com/2014/01/eval.html
http://blog.klipse.tech/javascript/2016/06/20/js-eval-secrets.html

Answer (score 4):

If you do something like:

```
this.TestClass.call("this");
```

and in the TestCalss:

```
console.log(eval(pString));
```

You will find that it logs as the `window` object. The string `this` won't take the context with itself. If you would had logged, `window.arrTest1`, this would had given you the desired result.

So...

You need to pass the context:

```
this.TestClass.Run.call(this, "this.arrTest1 = [1]");
```

And in your TestCalss

```
TestClass = {
    Run : (pString) => {
      return eval(pString)
    }
};
```

> **Why does eval.call(this, pString) not work?**

There is something different about how `eval()` works. `eval()` is not a real javascript function. As answered here: [How override eval function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566973/how-override-eval-function-in-javascript#answer-2567001)

As you have already tried in your question, you did something like:

```
(0, eval)(pString); // this is an indirect call to eval
```

What is an indirect call??

> According to ES5, all of these are indirect calls and should execute code in global scope

The gloabl scope in your case will be nothing, typescript by default doesn't provide a global scope. (As far I know)

There's a very comprehensive description about `eval` written here: 
http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/

According to the above link, following are some of the examples of indirect `eval` calls :

```
(1, eval)('...')
(eval, eval)('...')
(1 ? eval : 0)('...')
(__ = eval)('...')
var e = eval; e('...')
(function(e) { e('...') })(eval)
(function(e) { return e })(eval)('...')
(function() { arguments[0]('...') })(eval)
this.eval('...')
this['eval']('...')
[eval][0]('...')
eval.call(this, '...')  <-- This is your case.
eval('eval')('...')
```

Another paragraph from the article:

> Not understanding what’s going on, some people unfortunately come up with rather monstrous solutions like eval.call(window, '...'), window.eval.call(window, '...') and even scarier combinations. All of those are, once again, nothing but indirect eval calls.

There's also a very nice paragraph describing why `(0, eval)(pString)` is indirect. Please have a look. Unfortunately, I could find any proper reason to justify why `eval.call(this, '...')` is indirect. Maybe we will have to satisfy with the statement like `eval()` is not a real function().

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, wish I could mark 2 answers :( Unfortunately e.m.b answered first with a good explanation as well so I feel like the answer belongs to him. Thank you though! :)

Comment: @Frank: Yeah! No problem :)

Comment: @Frank: Adding to e.m.b 's answer, I have added few points in my answer about why `eval.call()` doesn't work. Please have a look.

Comment: Wow thank you man! So does this mean that there is no possible way to fix the use of eval? Your and e.m.b's answers do solve the problem. But I am looking for a way to understand how to solve the eval problem at class level. Look at this question of mine where I phrased this question better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295983/understanding-eval-reference

Comment: @Frank: I am out of work now, I will have a look at it and update you about it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with eval and ended up using the following IIFE.

Expressions are coming from a backend something like: "Client === 123". No option to change them.

"eval" will not understand it directly. Since in TS member variables are accessed with the "this" keyword. Something like "this.Client" etc.

One possible workaround is to have a function and add required variables inside it then invoke eval.

```
  testEval(expression: HTMLInputElement) {
    const result = (() => {
      const Client = this.clientNumber;
      return eval(expression.value);
    })();

    this.expressionResult = `expression: [${expression.value}], result: [${result}]`;
  }
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eval-iife-test?file=src/app/app.component.ts)