# Understanding Eval Reference

Tags: angular, typescript, eval

I know that there are other threads on this topic but I am asking again because I am really trying hard to understand eval and how to use it correctly so that it doesn't become evil. By looking at this code, how can I get the `console.log(this.arrTest);` to log `['Back to Original']`? I tried many variations and none of them work.

I do **not** want this solution please: `this.TestClass.Run.call(this, "this.arrTest = ['Back to Original'];");` I want a solution inside the class level.

Here is an angular blitz to play with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtuvvz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  arrTest = ['Original'];

  constructor() {
    this.TestClass.Run("this.arrTest = ['Back to Original'];");
    console.log(this.arrTest);
  };

  TestClass = {
    Run : (pString) => {
      this.arrTest = ['Changed']; //So this works

      eval(pString); //Why is this not working
      eval.call(this, pString); //Why is this not working
      eval.call(null, pString); //Why is this not working
      (1, eval)(pString); //Why is this not working
      (eval)(pString); //Why is this not working
      var my_eval = eval; //Why is this not working
      my_eval(pString); //Why is this not working
    }
  };

}
```

I have read both of these articles but I don't understand a solution from them:

http://2ality.com/2014/01/eval.html

http://blog.klipse.tech/javascript/2016/06/20/js-eval-secrets.html

Comment: don't really have time to dig deep into how eval work but I guess here you'll find answer: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2

Comment: Holy crap man I am not at the level to be able to work through this! XD

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make `eval` not 'evil' in this case, because it is evil. An appropriate idiomatic solution should be used instead.

```
  eval(pString);
  (eval)(pString);
```

are the ways it's supposed to be workable, they are essentially the same because wrapping `eval` with parentheses does nothing. The rest of `eval`s are used indirectly, this results in evaluating the code in global scope.

This will work only with ES6 target. It can be seen what the class [transpiles to](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20AppComponent%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20arrTest%20%3D%20%5B%27Original%27%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.TestClass.Run(%22this.arrTest%20%3D%20%5B%27Back%20to%20Original%27%5D%3B%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.arrTest)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20TestClass%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Run%20%3A%20(pString)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20this.arrTest%20%3D%20%5B%27Changed%27%5D%3B%20%2F%2FSo%20this%20works%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20eval(pString)%3B%20%2F%2FWhy%20is%20this%20not%20working%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20eval.call(this%2C%20pString)%3B%20%2F%2FWhy%20is%20this%20not%20working%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20eval.call(null%2C%20pString)%3B%20%2F%2FWhy%20is%20this%20not%20working%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20(1%2C%20eval)(pString)%3B%20%2F%2FWhy%20is%20this%20not%20working%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20(eval)(pString)%3B%20%2F%2FWhy%20is%20this%20not%20working%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20my_eval%20%3D%20eval%3B%20%2F%2FWhy%20is%20this%20not%20working%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20my_eval(pString)%3B%20%2F%2FWhy%20is%20this%20not%20working%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D) with ES5 target, `var _this = this` trick is used to pass `this` from enclosing scope to arrow function. `this` remains unchanged inside `Run` method and is `TestClass` object, not class instance. For this reason

```
this.TestClass.Run("_this.arrTest = ['Back to Original'];");
```

will work with ES5 but not ES6 TypeScript target.

This is a good example that shows why `eval` is considered 'evil'. It results in untyped, unpredictable, unsafe and unoptimized mess that could be avoided by following 'good' coding practices.

It's unclear what are the requirements for `TestClass.Run` but usually such scenarios are handled with callbacks:

```
  constructor() {
    this.TestClass.Run(() => {
      this.arrTest = ['Back to Original'];
    });
    console.log(this.arrTest);
  };

  TestClass = {
    Run : (cb: () => void) => {
     // class instance can be passed to callback as an argument
     // or cb.call(this) when needed
      cb();
    }
  };
```

Depending on what are the reasons to introduce `TestClass` member to execute code within the class it belongs to, this still may be considered unsuitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

So this solves the problem quite well in my scenario:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  arrTest = ['Original'];

  constructor() {
    this.TestClass.Run("arrTest", "['Back to Original']");
    console.log(this.arrTest);
  };

  TestClass = {
    Run : (pKey, pValue) => {
      this.arrTest = ['Changed']; //So this works

      this[pKey] = pValue;
    }
  };

}
```