# How to use variable class name in Angular 7 / Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

Creating an Angular 7 app, I defined a form component I use for different entities.

To do so, I create a variable route :

```
  {path: ':entity/create', component: FormComponent}
```

This work great, but depending on the entity I want to create, I have to load different object.

So I'm trying to instantiate a class using a variable class name in Angular.

I tried to do:

```
var object = eval('new myObject()');
```

But i got this error message :

```
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: myObject is not defined
@http://localhost:4200/main.js line 3199 > eval:1:1
./src/app/form/form.component.ts/FormComponent.prototype.ngOnInit/</<@http://localhost:4200/main.js:3199:24
step@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120599:18
verb/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120580:53
__awaiter/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120573:71
ZoneAwarePromise@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3268:29
__awaiter@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:120569:12
./src/app/form/form.component.ts/FormComponent.prototype.ngOnInit@http://localhost:4200/main.js:3195:16
checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:58018:9
checkAndUpdateNodeInline@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59282:20
checkAndUpdateNode@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59244:16
debugCheckAndUpdateNode@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59878:19
debugCheckDirectivesFn@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59838:13
View_FormComponent_Host_0/<@ng:///AppModule/FormComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:9:5
debugUpdateDirectives@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59830:12
checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59226:5
callViewAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59467:21
execEmbeddedViewsAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59430:17
checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59227:5
callViewAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59467:21
execComponentViewsAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59409:13
checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59232:5
callWithDebugContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:60096:22
debugCheckAndUpdateView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:59798:12
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ViewRef_.prototype.detectChanges@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:57607:13
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ApplicationRef.prototype.tick/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:54038:58
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ApplicationRef.prototype.tick@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:54038:13
next/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:53929:99
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2749:17
onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:53218:24
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2748:37
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2508:24
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/NgZone.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:53132:16
next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:53929:69
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49434:36
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:100897:13
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:100835:17
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype._next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:100778:9
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:100755:13
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js/Subject.prototype.next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:100520:25
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/EventEmitter.prototype.emit@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49418:54
checkStable@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:53187:13
onHasTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:53231:21
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.hasTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2801:21
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype._updateTaskCount@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2821:17
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype._updateTaskCount@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2649:34
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2570:25
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:2959:25
```

Is there a way to use a variable class name in Angular 7 / TypeScript?

Am I using Angular incorrectly?

Comment: Why don't you create a route for each possible entity ? with a generict component typed with that entity for example

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50291939/379855

Comment: Or you could just keep your route with the `:entity` variable but switch over the entity values and call new on the different classes

Comment: Could you share more code ? what are the entities, how are you loading the object and what are they used for ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You would need to fill your Variable not with an Object of Type newObject. Instead you had to fill it with the Type newObject. ( Dump the new ...())

Second: You can't use the router like this.

```
RoutesModule.forRoot(APP_Routes);
```

is just getting called once, and you can't change the routes afterwards. What you can do is define more routes or define a route with a variable at the end. 
For example '/splitter/:id' with splitter being a component that returns different Components based on id. But that is way easier done with child components.
See this:

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'crises', component: ManageCrisesComponent },
            { path: 'heroes', component: ManageHeroesComponent },
            { path: '', component: AdminDashboardComponent }
        ]}
];
```

(taken from the [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router)