# Jest testing function that calls eval

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I have a Vue TS project created with vue-cli 3.0.

This is the function I will test:

```js
public hopJavascript(url: string) {
    eval(url);
}
```

And this is my test function using Jest framework:

```js
test('navigation using javascript', () => {
    const url = "someurl";
    hopJavascript(url);
    
    expect(eval).toBeCalled();
});
```

Now i get this message,[test failed console logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAgo1.png) which is telling me that I need a mocked version of eval.

**How can i mock eval** ?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

It seems you can't always override eval based on your JS environment (browser or node). See the answer to ["How override eval function in javascript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2567001/10721492) for more information

**Original answer**

<s>I think you can redefine `eval` in your test file:</s>

```
global.eval = jest.fn()
```

Comment: Then it says [ts] Cannot find name 'global'. [2304], do you know how to get ts recognize this

Comment: After some research, it looks like you cannot always override eval

Comment: Nice, but it is old, maybe something changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track your function with spyOn().

This solution should work for you.

```
import MyClass from '../MyClass';

test('navigation using javascript', () => {
    const url = "someurl";
    const spy = jest.spyOn(MyClass, 'eval');

    MyClass.hopJavascript(url);

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```